# What is the function of "Use" in Agent Options and how to use it?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, agent

I'm not usually using Agent in Lotus Notes because I always Lotusscript button only. But recently I need to do a function in Lotus Notes using using an Agent. So in some of an Agent, I found this:

```
Option Public
Option Declare

Use "ParametersMaster"
Use "CommonFunctions"
Use "Class.QueryString"

Some Lotusscript code...
```

I don't really understand what are the functions of these "Use" and where to find them. I know this is kinda simple question and I would like somebody help me on this to understand what it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Use" commands loads external script libraries. Usually these script libraries are found in the same database under the Script Libraries design elements.

Refer to the Help in Designer for a much better answer

Comment: Oh, so when I created script libraries, I can called it using "Use" in Agent? Okay, I understand it now. Thank you!